How to retrieve a single record from the Room database
I tried to retrieve a single record from Room database but it gives me a null value. Here is my code:
GroupDAO.kt
@Dao
interface GroupDAO {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM groups")
    fun getAllGroups(): Flow<List<Group>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM groups WHERE groupId = :groupId")
    fun getGroupById(groupId: Int): Group?

    @Insert
    suspend fun insertGroup(group: Group): Long

    @Update
    suspend fun updateGroup(group: Group)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteGroup(group: Group)

    @Query("DELETE FROM groups")
    suspend fun deleteAllGroups()
}

GroupRepository.kt
class GroupRepository (application: Application) {
    private var groupDao: GroupDAO = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application).groupDAO()
    val allGroups: Flow<List<Group>> = groupDao.getAllGroups()

    suspend fun getGroupById(groupId: Int): Group? {
        return groupDao.getGroupById(groupId)
    }

    suspend fun insert(group: Group): Long {
        return groupDao.insertGroup(group)
    }

    suspend fun delete(group: Group) {
        groupDao.deleteGroup(group)
    }

    suspend fun update(group: Group) {
        groupDao.updateGroup(group)
    }

    suspend fun deleteAllGroups() {
        groupDao.deleteAllGroups()
    }
}

GroupViewModel.kt
class GroupViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val groupRepository: GroupRepository
    private val inviteRepository: InviteRepository
    init {
        groupRepository = GroupRepository(application)
        inviteRepository = InviteRepository(application)
    }

    val allGroups: LiveData<List<Group>> = groupRepository.allGroups.asLiveData()
   val group = mutableStateOf<Group?>(null)


    fun getGroupById(groupId: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            group.value = groupRepository.getGroupById(groupId)
        }
    }

    fun insertGroup(group: Group, users: List<User>) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val groupIdLong = groupRepository.insert(group)
        val groupId = groupIdLong.toInt()
        users.forEach { user ->
            val invite = Invite(0, user.userId, groupId, false)
            inviteRepository.insert(invite)
        }
    }
    fun updateGroup(group: Group) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        groupRepository.update(group)
    }
    fun deleteGroup(group: Group) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        groupRepository.delete(group)
    }

    fun deleteAllGroups() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            groupRepository.deleteAllGroups()
        }
    }

}

EditGroup.kt
@Composable
fun EditGroup(groupViewModel: GroupViewModel, groupId: Int) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    )
    {

        LaunchedEffect(groupId) {
            groupViewModel.getGroupById(groupId)
        }

        val currentGroup = groupViewModel.group.value
    }
}

I tried looking across Github, Medium, and other online resources on how to do this and align with my current code but it still does not work.

I don't see any issues above, except potentially that you are not using a singleton reference for either your repository or your database. Can you share the code of your groups entity?
